# Play video via social media reaction (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram)

Tags: facebook, video, twitter, web-applications, social-media

I'm looking for an approach to an interactive installation.
We will dispose several tablets on a wall from where we want to show some videos.
We would like to launch those videos depending on social media reactions, such as a "Like" on Facebook or a hashtag on Twitter (for example).

That means,for instance, when you like some specific content on Facebook, a video is played (but not a Facebook video; content can be stored wherever). 
Any direction to start research?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do

Comment: I tried a better explanation.Let me know if you got it now.
Thank you!

Comment: I think that might fall under ”incentivizing likes”, and that is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy.

Comment: But...
1) Videos are stored outside Facebook
2) There is no more reward but changing the current video playing...
Thanks!